# homebrew: how to tell if a formula is binary

Tags: command-line, homebrew

How do I tell if a particular formula will be installed as binary of from source?

Is there a brew command for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `brew edit ${formula_name}`. That will open an editor with the formula contents. If there is a reference to a "bottle", then installing it with default settings will use that. 
However, if you add an option, then homebrew will compile the software for you.